# Deploy to GKE from CI server outside of cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, google-cloud-platform

I'm setting up our CI (Jenkins pipeline) to deploy apps to a GKE cluster. Our Jenkins sever is running external to GKE or any Google Cloud infrastructure. I'm thinking of using [a docker image with helm and kubectl](https://github.com/dtzar/helm-kubectl) to deploy, but need to set up credentials. On my local dev machine, I authenticate with:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]
```

What would be the best way of setting up credentials for a Jenkins job? Do I have to install and use the `gcloud` tools on Jenkins, or is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach does appear to be to use `gcloud`, as trying to get a kubeconfig without it proved tricky.

Fortunately, `gcloud`, `kubectl` and `helm` are available as a single docker image `kiwigrid/gcloud-kubectl-helm`. For example:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume ./gcp-key-file.json:/data/gcp-key-file.json:ro kiwigrid/gcloud-kubectl-helm:2.11.0-224.0.0 bash
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/data/gcp-key-file.json
gcloud container clusters get-credentials dev-cluster --project <project name> --zone <zone>
```